Сenter only the visible portion of vertically scrolling content (not the entire available height) in Jetpack Compose
I have a screen like this with two tabs and a collapsing header:

This screen has the following layout:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:background="@color/black"
            app:contentScrim="@color/black"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:title="header title" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
        android:id="@+id/compose_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

I need to center the error content (tab 2) vertically, but not to the full height of the available scroll in ComposeView, but only in the state when the header is maximally expanded. That is, I need to find verticalPadding as in this screenshot:

I managed to do it, but I think there must be an easier way to achieve the same result, here's what I did:
@Composable
private fun InfoContent(title: String, subtitle: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column(
        modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .wrapContentWidth()
    ) {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp),
            painter = painterResource(android.R.drawable.ic_delete),
            contentDescription = null
        )
        Text(title, style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge)
        Text(subtitle, style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium)
    }
}

@Composable
private fun ErrorContent(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    verticalPaddingPx: MutableIntState,
    headerHeightPx: Int,
) {
    val screenHeightPx = LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp.dp.dpToPx()
    val (title, subtitle) = "error title" to "error subtitle"

    LazyColumn(modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        item {
            if (verticalPaddingPx.intValue == -1) {
                Layout(
                    content = { InfoContent(title, subtitle) },
                    measurePolicy = { measurables, constraints ->
                        val placeables = measurables.map { it.measure(constraints) }

                        val width = constraints.maxWidth
                        val errorHeight = placeables.sumOf { it.height }
                        val verticalPadding = (screenHeightPx - headerHeightPx - errorHeight) / 2
                        verticalPaddingPx.intValue = verticalPadding

                        layout(width, errorHeight) {
                            var yPosition = verticalPadding
                            placeables.forEach { placeable ->
                                placeable.placeRelative(x = 0, y = yPosition)
                                yPosition += placeable.height
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
            } else {
                InfoContent(
                    title,
                    subtitle,
                    Modifier.padding(vertical = verticalPaddingPx.intValue.pxToDp()),
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

before the very first call to ErrorContent I remember the value like this:
val verticalPaddingPx = rememberSaveable { mutableIntStateOf(-1) }

Yes, I use LazyColumn for one element. Using Box or Column with Modifier.fillMaxSize().verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
doesn't allow scrolling the second tab anywhere, I don't know why.
if I do this:
@Composable
private fun ErrorContent(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val (title, subtitle) = "error title" to "error subtitle"

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    ) {
        item {
            InfoContent(title, subtitle)
        }
    }
}

then I will get incorrect centering (across the entire available scroll height):


here is my whole code:
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        supportActionBar?.hide()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val header = findViewById<CollapsingToolbarLayout>(R.id.header)
        val composeView = findViewById<ComposeView>(R.id.compose_view).apply {
            setViewCompositionStrategy(
                ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed
            )
        }

        header.post {
            composeView.setContent {
                val nestedScrollInteropConnection = rememberNestedScrollInteropConnection()

                CenteringTheErrorScreenTheme {
                    HomeScreen(
                        modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(nestedScrollInteropConnection),
                        initialTabIndex = 0,
                        titles = TabTitle.entries.map { it.text },
                        headerHeightPx = header.height,
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

enum class TabTitle(val text: String) {
    Tab1("Tab 1"),
    Tab2("Tab 2"),
}

@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    initialTabIndex: Int?,
    titles: List<String> = emptyList(),
    headerHeightPx: Int,
) {
    val verticalPaddingPx = rememberSaveable { mutableIntStateOf(-1) }

    if (initialTabIndex != null && titles.isNotEmpty()) {
        TabsContent(modifier, initialTabIndex, titles, verticalPaddingPx, headerHeightPx)
    } else {
        ErrorContent(modifier, verticalPaddingPx, headerHeightPx)
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
private fun TabsContent(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    initialTabIndex: Int,
    titles: List<String>,
    verticalPaddingPx: MutableIntState,
    headerHeightPx: Int,
) {
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(initialTabIndex) { titles.size }

    Column(modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        TabRow(pagerState) {
            titles.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
                Tab(pagerState, index, title)
            }
        }

        HorizontalPager(pagerState, verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top) { tabIndex ->
            TabContent(TabTitle.entries[tabIndex], verticalPaddingPx, headerHeightPx)
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
private fun TabRow(pagerState: PagerState, tabs: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    TabRow(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        containerColor = Color.White,
        selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage,
        tabs = tabs,
    )
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
private fun Tab(pagerState: PagerState, tabIndex: Int, title: String) {
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    Tab(
        selected = pagerState.currentPage == tabIndex,
        onClick = {
            coroutineScope.launch {
                pagerState.animateScrollToPage(tabIndex)
            }
        }
    ) {
        Text(title, modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 10.dp))
    }
}

@Composable
private fun TabContent(
    tab: TabTitle,
    verticalPaddingPx: MutableIntState,
    headerHeightPx: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    when (tab) {
        TabTitle.Tab1 -> ItemsContent(modifier)
        TabTitle.Tab2 -> ErrorContent(modifier, verticalPaddingPx, headerHeightPx)
    }
}

@Composable
private fun ItemsContent(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    LazyColumn(modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        items(100) { index ->
            Text(
                text = "Item #$index",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(16.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun ErrorContent(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    verticalPaddingPx: MutableIntState,
    headerHeightPx: Int,
) {
    val screenHeightPx = LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp.dp.dpToPx()
    val (title, subtitle) = "error title" to "error subtitle"

    LazyColumn(modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        item {
            if (verticalPaddingPx.intValue == -1) {
                Layout(
                    content = { InfoContent(title, subtitle) },
                    measurePolicy = { measurables, constraints ->
                        val placeables = measurables.map { it.measure(constraints) }

                        val width = constraints.maxWidth
                        val errorHeight = placeables.sumOf { it.height }
                        val verticalPadding = (screenHeightPx - headerHeightPx - errorHeight) / 2
                        verticalPaddingPx.intValue = verticalPadding

                        layout(width, errorHeight) {
                            var yPosition = verticalPadding
                            placeables.forEach { placeable ->
                                placeable.placeRelative(x = 0, y = yPosition)
                                yPosition += placeable.height
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
            } else {
                InfoContent(
                    title,
                    subtitle,
                    Modifier.padding(vertical = verticalPaddingPx.intValue.pxToDp()),
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun InfoContent(title: String, subtitle: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column(
        modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .wrapContentWidth()
    ) {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp),
            painter = painterResource(android.R.drawable.ic_delete),
            contentDescription = null
        )
        Text(title, style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge)
        Text(subtitle, style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium)
    }
}

@Composable
fun Int.pxToDp(): Dp {
    val density = LocalContext.current.resources.displayMetrics.density
    return (this / density).dp
}

@Composable
fun Dp.dpToPx(): Int {
    val density = LocalContext.current.resources.displayMetrics.density
    return (this.value * density).toInt()
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
private fun MyComposeContentPreview() {
    CenteringTheErrorScreenTheme {
        val headerHeightDp = 200.dp
        val headerHeightPx = headerHeightDp.dpToPx()

        Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            Box(
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(headerHeightDp)
                    .background(color = Color.Black)
            )
            HomeScreen(
                modifier = Modifier.offset(y = (-16).dp),
                initialTabIndex = 1,
                titles = emptyList(),
                headerHeightPx = headerHeightPx,
            )
        }
    }
}

